# Compare two atomic variables in C++?

Tags: c++, atomic

I learned about `atomic variables`, and know the operation of `atomic variables`.

Next, I want to use `atomic variables` to implement a bounded `lock-free queue`. I plan to use two variables to represent the head and tail of the queue.

```
template <typename T>
class BoundedQueue {
 public:
  void enqueue(const T& t);
 private:
  T* data_;
  std::atomic<uint64_t> head_;
  std::atomic<uint64_t> tail_;
};

template <typename T>
void BoundedQueue::enqueue(const T& t) {
  auto h_t = head_.load();
  while(!head_.compare_exchange_weak(h_t, h_t+1)) {
    ;
  }
  data_[h_t] = t;
}
```

1. Although enqueue can increase atomically. But `I can’t know if the queue is full`, otherwise I need to implement the following logic

```
if (head_.load() > tail_.load() + capacity) {
  // the queue is full
}
```

I know that the above process is not atomic, but how do I get the length of the current queue?

2. I see the following comparison in `folly`'s `folly\ProducerConsumerQueue.h`

```
  bool isEmpty() const {
    return readIndex_.load(std::memory_order_acquire) ==
        writeIndex_.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
  }
```

Can someone explain the reason in detail?

---

### additional

I understand the implementation in folly, because it restricts SPSC, so the producer thread only needs to know the value of head_, and it knows the value of tail by itself, so it can be guaranteed to be atomic, but once it leaves SPSC, it doesn’t hold.

```
 * ProducerConsumerQueue is a one producer and one consumer queue
 * without locks.
```

Comment: Aside: you can `head_.fetch_add(1)` (aka `++head`) instead of load / compare_exchange_weak

Comment: Why do you want to implement it on atomic instead of using std::lock_guard on std::mutex ?